# oracle: why cant i insert into view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, insert

I created a simple view with columns from a single table. When i try to insert values into the table, i get the ORA_01732 error that dml is not legal on this view. I DO have an order by clause in the view definition which I've gathered is not allowed for it to be inherently updatable and I'm seeing that I probably have to use an INSTEAD OF type clause in the view definition. Can someone show me how I would build the view to be updatable this way?

here is the create view statement:

```
create view CUST_VIEW
as select customer#,firstname,lastname,state
from book_customer
order by state, lastname;
```

Comment: You'd have to post the CREATE VIEW statement for us to be able to advise how to make it updatable.  `ORDER BY` in a view is highly questionable, and not a recommended practice.

Comment: Why would anyone use an order by in a view?

Comment: its a homework assignment that tells me to define the view so that it orders by last name within each state. updated question with the create view

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the `order by` is the cause for your observation?

I can do an insert on a view with an order by clause:

```
create table tq84_table (
  a number,
  b number
);

create view tq84_updateable_view as
select a, b from tq84_table 
order by a;


insert into tq84_table values (4,1);
insert into tq84_table values (1,4);
insert into tq84_table values (3,9);
insert into tq84_table values (7,5);

select * from tq84_updateable_view;

insert into tq84_updateable_view values (1,9);

select * from tq84_updateable_view;
```

The above statements run with no problem on Oracle 11 R2.

You might want to check with `USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS` which columns you can insert to:

```
SQL> select * from user_updatable_columns where table_name = 'TQ84_UPDATEABLE_VIEW';

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                    UPD INS DEL
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ --- --- ---
RENE                           TQ84_UPDATEABLE_VIEW           A                              YES YES YES
RENE                           TQ84_UPDATEABLE_VIEW           B                              YES YES YES
```

Comment: i checked user_updatable_coumns and it says that each column that im trying to update is updatable but it still gives me that error

Answer (score 1):

You are right that a view with ORDER BY clause is not inherently updatable. All you have to do is create an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view to execute the INSERT you want. 
Eg: Lets say you have a view  ACTIVE_CUST_VIEW on table ALL_CUST

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INS_NEW_CUST_VIEW
INSTEAD OF INSERT
ON ACTIVE_CUST_VIEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ALL_CUST (CUST_ID,CUST_NAME,START_DATE) VALUES (:NEW.CUST_ID,:NEW.CUST_NAME,:NEW.START_DATE);
END INS_NEW_CUST_VIEW;
/
```